# GIF stops animating when form submit button is clicked in iOS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari, frontend

I have a GIF on the clicking of the Submit button.

And it is working fine on all operating systems except iOS, especially on Mobile devices.

DIV structure is as follows:

```
<div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image" src="' . $loader_base64 . '" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Where `$loader_base64` is a `base64 | data-uri` of GIF image. I have tried keeping normal URI of the image as well. but it is not working.

I am showing Loading GIF by this JS code:

```
jQuery( "#search-form .btn" ).ready( function(){
    jQuery( "#search-form .btn, #search-bottom" ).click(function() {
        jQuery('#loading').show();
        jQuery("html, body").css( "overflow", "hidden" );
    });
} );
```

When I am submitting the form, GIF stops animating because a new browser request has been initialized immediately.

What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: use the submit event rather than the click

Comment: @MisterJojo, Tried! but did not work.